# Getting 500 | Internal Server Error when using getServerSideProps in NextJS after deploying in Vercel

Tags: next.js, server-side-rendering, vercel

I'm using server rendered pages in NextJS using getServerSideProps. It's in index.js (root page).
When I'm making build locally, website working fine. But when i'm hosting this site in Vercel, it's showing 500 | Internal Server error.

```
export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  let params = context.query;

  const job_col = await collection(db, "job_list");
  const job_snap = await getDocs(job_col);
  let jobData = job_snap.docs.map((doc) => ({
    ...doc.data(),
    id: doc.id,
  }));
  
  return {
    props: {
      jobs: jobData,
      params
    },
  };
}
```

Comment: Have you added environment variables in vercel

Comment: What error do you see in Vercel's logs?

Comment: @HussamKhatib there is no environment variables used in this project

Comment: @juliomalves Build logs looks fine. there is no errors in vercel logs. But the root page is returning 500 status code

Comment: I didn't mean the build logs, I meant the Functions logs. If the page is throwing a 500 error, there will be logs on Vercel about it.

Comment: Thanks you @juliomalves, found some errors with firebase in function logs. I moved the get request code from SSR function to useEffect, now it's working fine. But, Why firebase get request is not working SSR, but working in client side?

Comment: I was in the same situation, and did the same thing. The reason is because Vercel free host has a limit of 5 secs to load any page. You can solve this upgrading ur vercel account. I still couldn't find a way to make firebase work with SSR.

Answer (score -2):

It's because of the large payload. Move the large payload code portion to the client-side(useEffect) and it will be resolved.

Comment: I got a similar problem (I generate over 50k pages with ISR). Locally the app builds fine. Would we call the Next.js api with useEffect?

Answer (score -2):

I had the same issue. But when I changed getserversideprops to getstaticprops it worked.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).